# ArcObjects: esriSRGeoTransformation enum for WGS_1984_Major_Auxiliary_Sphere_To_WGS_1984

Tags: arcobjects

There is geoTransformation named:

WGS_1984_Major_Auxiliary_Sphere_To_WGS_1984

I know it exists because I can access it with Projection Tool in ArcToolbox.  But for the life of me I cannot find it any of the geoTransformation constant lists (esriSRGeoTransformationType, esriSRGeoTransformation2Type, esriSRGeoTransformation3Type). How do I access the enum for this geotransformation with ArcObjects?

Comment: Still not sure what the enum is, but its value is 108100. This code:

`ISpatialReferenceFactory2 spatialReferenceFactory2 = new SpatialReferenceEnvironmentClass();

IGeoTransformation geoTransformation = spatialReferenceFactory2.CreateGeoTransformation(108100) as IGeoTransformation;

Console.Write(geoTransformation.Name);`

Will print:
"WGS_1984_Major_Auxiliary_Sphere_To_WGS_1984"
ESRI appears to have omitted this enum from the ArcObjects Library Reference (Geometry).  Very annoying.

Comment: The code [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14113/how-to-use-arcobjects-to-choose-geotransformation) could be adapted to find a geotransformation by name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rgwozdz states, it's 108100. The enums have not been kept up-to-date. Up-to-date geographic/datum transformation lists are [here](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/21327). I'm actively working on publishing up-to-date documentation for all the various projection engine objects for ArcGIS 10.1.

Note: I work for Esri.