# Dynamic defining of transformation type for ISpatialReferenceFactory.CreateGeoTransformation call

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, coordinate-system

Suppose given a point (IPoint) in some coordinate system. Required to transform it to another coordinate system. If both of coordinate systems are predefined, we can use `IGeometry2.ProjectEx` with transformation specified by corresponded constant from `esriSRGeoTransformationType`, `esriSRGeoTransformation2Type`, or `esriSRGeoTransformation3Type` enumerations.

The code looks like ([source](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/Java/engine_samples/Geometry.Project_a_point_with_ProjectEx/example.html))

```
package arcgissamples.geometry;

import com.esri.arcgis.geometry.*;
import com.esri.arcgis.system.*;

public class ProjectGeometry {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      EngineInitializer.initializeEngine();
      AoInitialize aoInit = new AoInitialize();

      // Create a point with Geographic coordinates...
      Point point = new Point();
      point.putCoords(-100.0, 40.0);

      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("Original coordinates: " + point.getX() + ","
                + point.getY());

      // Create the SpatialReferenceEnvironment...
      SpatialReferenceEnvironment spatialReferenceEnvironment = new SpatialReferenceEnvironment();

      // Apply the initial spatial reference...
      ISpatialReference geographicCoordinateSystem = spatialReferenceEnvironment
                .createGeographicCoordinateSystem(esriSRGeoCSType.esriSRGeoCS_NAD1927);
      point.setSpatialReferenceByRef(geographicCoordinateSystem);

      // Create the output projected coordinate system...
      ISpatialReference projectedCoordinateSystem = spatialReferenceEnvironment
                .createProjectedCoordinateSystem(esriSRProjCSType.esriSRProjCS_NAD1983UTM_13N);

      // Create the GeoTransformation...
      //***************************************************
      // !!!! How to define arg for createGeoTransformation??
      IGeoTransformation iGeoTransformation = (IGeoTransformation) spatialReferenceEnvironment
                .createGeoTransformation(esriSRGeoTransformationType.esriSRGeoTransformation_NAD1927_To_WGS1984_5);

      // Project the point...
      point.projectEx(projectedCoordinateSystem, esriTransformDirection.esriTransformForward,
                iGeoTransformation, false, 0.0, 0.0);
      System.out.println("Projected coordinates: " + point.getX() + " , "
                + point.getY());

      System.out.println("Done!");

      aoInit.shutdown();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

But problem is that both original coordinate system and output coordinate system are defining at the time of program execution. So I need a function to define constant for `ISpatialReferenceFactory.CreateGeoTransformation` method like

```
int defineTransformationType(ISpatialReference srcCoordSystem, ISpatialReference destCoordSys)
```

Is it possible? And how to implement this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of *creating* a geotransformation, I would try *finding* one.  This can be done by looping through all the predefined geotransformations via `CreatePredefinedGeographicTransformations` and checking to see if the input and output spatialreferenceID's match the GCS's of your spatialreferences.

See code at [Using ArcObjects to choose GeoTransformation?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14113/using-arcobjects-to-choose-geotransformation).