# Recommendations on universal projection API or algorithm for ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, coordinate-system

As asked on the esri forum [here](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/69471-Universal-Projection-API-Algorithm), we are trying to convert a geometry from any spatial reference to any other spatial reference. We have tried the default *IGeometry.Project*(target_spatial_reference) but with no success.
We then turned our attention to *IGeometry.ProjectEx*(...), but some of the sample data we have does not use a well-nknownn ID (FactoryCode) and we can't find a canned, out-of-the-box GeoTransformation to convert our geometry.

We did follow the recommendations in both responses in [this other thread here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14113/how-to-use-arcobjects-to-choose-geotransformation), but with no succes.

Does anybody here know of an esri API that can project a geometry from any spatial reference to any other spatial reference?

Or, can anybody point us to a code sample or algorithm to properly and accurately project a geometry to/from any spatial reference?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Eric.

Comment: Assuming you had a resource that gave you a list of all the applicable geotransformations for transforming between two different datums, how would you expect the algorithm to choose the "best" one?  I wonder if the folks at [spatialreference.org](http://www.spatialreference.org/) have considered providing an API whereby you could zoom in on an area on the map and see a list of geotransforms and/or projections.