# Geographic transformations and ArcPy gives ERROR 000365?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.1

I have a script that goes through all the rasters in a particular folder and then reprojects it to another coordinate system, using arcpy.

My problem is that i keep on getting the following:

> ERROR 000365: Invalid geographic transformation.

My code fails on this line

```
        arcpy.ProjectRaster_management(raster, in_memoryLayer, "British National Grid.prj","#", "#", transformation,"#", "#")
```

I have set the transformation to the following

```
transformation = "OSGB_1936_To_WGS_1984_7"
```

and have also tried

```
transformation = "PROJCS['British_National_Grid',GEOGCS['GCS_OSGB_1936',DATUM['D_OSGB_1936',SPHEROID['Airy_1830',6377563.396,299.3249646]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',400000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',-100000.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',-2.0],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9996012717],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',49.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]", "NEAREST", "0.516860387597052", "OSGB_1936_To_WGS_1984_7", "", "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433],METADATA['World',-180.0,-90.0,180.0,90.0,0.0,0.0174532925199433,0.0,1262]]"
```

I got the above from exporting a model from modelbuilder.

but i still get the error.

Here is the code for the ProjectRaster tool that is exported from ModelBuilder

```
arcpy.ProjectRaster_management(inputRaster, convertedRaster, "PROJCS['British_National_Grid',GEOGCS['GCS_OSGB_1936',DATUM['D_OSGB_1936',SPHEROID['Airy_1830',6377563.396,299.3249646]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',400000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',-100000.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',-2.0],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9996012717],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',49.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]", "NEAREST", "0.521227542928997", "OSGB_1936_To_WGS_1984_7", "", "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433],METADATA['World',-180.0,-90.0,180.0,90.0,0.0,0.0174532925199433,0.0,1262]]")
```

The above does not work when running from python, but the model itself does.

Any advice on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried running it without using `in_memory` inputs and outputs? I know the regular project tool [cannot use `in_memory` datasets for inputs and outputs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00vp0000000m000944).

Comment: Try using the full path of the projection, e.g. `"c:/ArcGIS/projections and coordinates or whatever/British National Grid.prj"`

Comment: @dmahr, tried that, made no difference

Comment: @Jason, tried that aswell, no difference, I can get it to work when I use modelbuilder but once exported it, i get the error.

Comment: Do you have the NTv2 grid installed? If not you need to download it (below) and put it in ArcGIS install, pedata/ntv2/uk: http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/support/os-net/ostn02-ntv2-format.html

Comment: @mkennedy,I've downloaded that, and have been using that from within ModelBuilder (which does work), I've edited the orig question with what the export to python script from modelbuilder for the ProjectRaster tool.

Answer (score 1):

Check your transformation, `OSGB_1936_To_WGS_1984_7`, against the list of valid transformations: `C:\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\Documentation\geographic_transformations.pdf`.

It is not listed in version of the document I have; only the following transformations for OSGB are valid:

[image]

Comment: Isn't there a spatial reference class method at 10.1 that lets you feed in 2 layers and it will return a list of the acceptable transformations between the 2? I'm not on 10.1 and I cannot find it in the docs right now.

Comment: This is an old list. The document was updated at 10.1.

Comment: He should still check it, unless you are saying that you already have and it exists in the 10.1 document.

Comment: @Jason, its in the 10.1 document. I think I might just stick with creating a model that iterates through my files as we know it works.

Comment: Chad, the tool you are looking for is: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/49119/10919 AND http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v0000001p000000