# ArcObjects: with transformation reprojected tiles are drawn with spaces

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects

I have used [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/14119/32766) Code from Kirk to choose a transformation if the spatial reference do not match when adding a layer with tiles. The tiles already got automatically reprojected to the existing spatialreference. I only added the `IGeoTransformation` and the transformation direction to the raster before being reprojected. As result the tiles get drawn but do not match and leave blank areas like this (it's getting worse with higher zoom levels):

[image: blank areas between tiles]

I do unterstand that this has to do with the transformation and is caused by the performed rotation and translation.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the Problem now by merging all tiles into one big tile right before displaying the layer. The projection and transformation is than applied to this "big tile".